# cannot select specific column after merging it with another data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
unitown=pd.merge(Q1(),Q5(),how='inner',left_on=['State','RegionName'],right_index=True)
```

i created this new data frame called unitown after merging two data frames with index 'State' and 'RegionName'. 
Below is how unitown looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vIb8.png)

from the pic you can see it has column named in the format of Year and Quarter. However when I try `unitown['2000Q1']` it gives me the following error:

```
 2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
KeyError: '2000Q1'*
```

I have tried `unitown.columns.tolist()` and below is part of the output:

```
['State',
 'RegionName',
 Period('2000Q1', 'Q-DEC'),
 Period('2000Q2', 'Q-DEC'),
 Period('2000Q3', 'Q-DEC'),
 Period('2000Q4', 'Q-DEC'),
 Period('2001Q1', 'Q-DEC'),
 Period('2001Q2', 'Q-DEC'),
 Period('2001Q3', 'Q-DEC'),
 Period('2001Q4', 'Q-DEC'),
 Period('2002Q1', 'Q-DEC'),
 Period('2002Q2', 'Q-DEC'),
 Period('2002Q3', 'Q-DEC'),
```

I am not sure why it gives such error given '2000Q1' is clearly one of the column names. Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make sure no extra space is there in the column name. Just share the output of `df.columns`

Comment: @sau hi sau I have just uploaded what df.columns look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should resolve the issue:

```
df.columns = [str(col) for col in df.columns]
```

Comment: Thanks sau this has solved my problem. Just a quick question do you know why I have to convert it to string in the first place? is it because of how I convert it into quarterly data using 'PeriodIndex(df.columns,freq=Q)' ? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Basically column names is not exactly what you were expecting. And you can accept the answer  :)